# Designing Server Side Timer/Countdown for a Quiz App

Tags: reactjs, backend

I am building a quiz app with Ionic React. I want to implement some kind of quiz timer/countdown feature to limit time spent on every question. The catch is, if I implement a countdown function on client side or Front-end, I'm afraid that folks could tamper with the script and cheat by manipulating the timer to their advantage.

Therefore, I think the only way to prevent this is to implement the timer/countdown feature server side. However, I do not know the right way to go about this... Wouldn't a countdown function blocks the server? Or is there some other way that I do not know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this:

**http:**

You can run a timer at frontend. Notify the backend with start / end timestamp of each question to calculate the duration taken for each question. If the duration falls within the allowed range, you are good to proceed. Here, frontend is your source of truth but you are validating it at the backend.

**websocket**:

Or you can implement a websocket to communicate in real time with the backend. In this case, you can run the timer at backend and show its progress at frontend in realtime. Backend will be your single source of truth.

You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145455/how-to-synchronize-backend-timer-with-mobile-app) too.